# Logical operation of a k8s multi-entry selector

Tags: kubernetes

This k8s service definition have multiple entries under `selector` section.

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
    tier: back-end
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376`

Which operation does this selector follows, `( app == my-app && tier == back-end )` or `( app == my-app || tier == back-end )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors)

> A label selector can be made of multiple requirements which are
>   comma-separated. In the case of multiple requirements, all must be
>   satisfied so the comma separator acts as a logical AND (&&) operator.
>
> Caution: For both equality-based and set-based conditions there is no
>   logical OR (||) operator. Ensure your filter statements are structured
>   accordingly